# WYSIWYG String escape key representation

Tags: string, escaping, d, wysiwyg

I've been writing a basic hex dump program in D. My program works as I expect it to, based on test files, but a key formatting function isn't passing the unittest I've written for it.

As the formatted output is exactly as I intended it, I concluded that my unittest doesn't express exactly what I wanted it to.

```
string getOutput(ubyte[] bin) {
    char[] hex =cast(char[]) ("\t\t0\t1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\n");
    for(int line; 8 * line < bin.length; line++) {
        if (8 * line + 8 >= bin.length) {
            hex ~= format("%0#0 10x%(\t%1 0 2x%)\n", line*8, bin[8*line..bin.length]);
        }
        else {
            hex ~= format("%0#0 10x%(\t%1 0 2x%)\n", line*8, bin[8*line..8*line + 8]);
        }
    }
    return cast(string) hex;
}

///Example of getOutput()
unittest {
    ubyte[9] a = [0xf0, 0xe1, 0xd2, 0xc3, 0xb4, 0xa5, 0x96, 0x87, 0x78];
    string b = getOutput(a);
    write(b);
    assert(b == 
r"           0   1   2   3   4   5   5   7
0000000000  f0  e1  d2  c3  b4  a5  96  87
0000000008  78
");
}
```

I included `write(b)` in the unit test to manually inspect the contents. Copy-pasted from my console, b is:

```
                0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7
0000000000      f0      e1      d2      c3      b4      a5      96      87
0x00000008      78
```

I've spent several hours reading the D lexical documentation for strings, but am nowhere closer to understanding my problem, hence I'm throwing it to you, in the hope I'm not missing something too obvious.

Many thanks.

Comment: Sooo when you copy/pasted the output to that unit test, did you keep the internal tabs or were they converted to spaces? The paste here on stack overflow shows spaces separating the fields, but your format string outputs tabs. Some terminals will convert tabs to spaces on copy paste, and some editors will to on save. So that's the first thing I'd check in the original file's test.

Comment: Your expected value has "5 5 7" not "5 6 7"!

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge. Ahahaha! I fail at life! How did I not see that? Thanks.